# git merge prompt "fatal: empty ident"

Tags: git, merge

when I want to merge change from the "cl" branch using git, I typed:

```
git merge "merge" HEAD cl
```

I got the following anwser:

> *** Please tell me who you are.
>
> Run
>
> git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
>     git config --global user.name "Your Name"
>
> to set your account's default identity. Omit --global to set the
>   identity only in this repository.
>
> fatal: empty ident   not allowed

So, I typed:

```
git config  chandler.chen "chen lei"
```

however, after config the account information, merge still get the former result.

Comment: You should really read the manual before you start playing with this. You need to type `git config --global user.email chenlei@gmail.com` and `git config --global user.name "Chen Lei"`.

Answer (score 11):

```
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

How exactly did this end up as `git config  chandler.chen "chen lei"` for you?!

Here's what you need to run:

```
git config --global user.email "put@your.email.address.here"
git config --global user.name "put your name or nickname here"
```

Comment: *** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: empty ident  <chen lei> not allowed

Comment: Which commands did you use exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Even after fixing the identity thing, I have no idea what that merge command is trying to do. It should probably be just `git merge cl`

Comment: I know why. I have to type two command, one to config "user.email" and another to config "user.name" so:

git config --global user.email chenlei@gmail.com
git config --global user.name "Chen Lei"
this worked