# git : empty ident name (for <>) not allowed

Tags: git, github

I was applying a [diff file](http://pastebin.ca/3759873) of an opensource project on the top of my repository using git-am :

```
 git am -3 < /Downloads/refactorWork.diff
```

but it had conflicts and i had to resolve them; but after resolving the conflicts and staging them, when i did git am --continue i got :

```
fatal : empty ident name (for <>) not allowed
```

I looked up on the internet and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583746/git-merge-prompt-fatal-empty-ident) which seemed to be similar to my problem but my usename and email were already added up in global and local git directories. Here is the output of git config list :

```
rohan@~/Documents/libo : $ git config --global --list
user.email=rohankanojia420@gmail.com
user.name=Rohan Kumar
alias.l=log --oneline --graph --pretty
credential.helper=cache
```

Although i solved this by first commiting the staged changes and then using `git am --skip`, I am interested in knowing what does that error means and whether what i did was the correct way of doing it, or is there any better way?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This diff file is a plain diff, not something generated by `git format-patch`. A `format-patch` generated diff contains information about the commit author, author date, commit message, ... and maintains this information when creating the commit(s).

Your plain diff does not have these information, so `git am` will complain that it is missing, naturally.

You should instead have used `git apply` which is meant to apply simple patch files like you have in this case which will only apply the patch to the worktree (and index if you tell it to) but does not create any commit automatically.

Comment: Oh, so it's complaining about the diff file. Thanks for clearing my doubt. I knew that the patch would result in conflicts. git apply would have failed in this case, that's why i used git am because i read that it shows the conflicts   and gives chance to resolve them.

Comment: As the patch in question has the blobs it is created against noted - given you have those blobs available in your repository - you could have used `-3` to fall back to a three-way merge, eventually resulting in files with conflict markers for you to resolve. Other than that you could have used `--reject` to apply the hunks that are applicable and create `.rej` files for the hunks that were not applicable to review and manually apply. Without any options, `apply` would fail the whole patch if something does not apply, that's correct. But internally `git am` also uses `git apply`.

Comment: Maybe `git am` would have worked without error by setting `GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL` and / or `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME` environment variables.

Comment: In case anyone's wondering, TortoiseGit's "Apply" button seems to actually run `git am`, not `git apply`. Also the "Create Patch Serial" button seems to create plain patches. (semi-related): I'm not sure if I missed something here or not but this seems like a strange design decision. It seems like Tortoise is setting people up for failure if it generates patches through the GUI that can't be used without falling back to git command line.

Comment: I don't think you used it correctly. If you use "Create Patch Serial" and you click "OK", it uses `format-patch` to create patches, if you use "Apply Patch Serial", it uses `am` to play back the patches. If you use "Create Patch Serial" and use "Save unified diff since HEAD", it creates a plain diff and that can be played back by right clicking the patch file and using "Review / Apply single patch". Even if you only have one `format-patch` generated patch file, you should use "Apply Patch Serial".

Comment: @Vampire your comment helped me to solve this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Use,

**git apply -3 patchName.patch**

when you encounter conflicts, open your mergtool and resolve conflicts

**git mergetool**

that's all :)

Answer (score 4):

*Moved out of comment to the accepted answer*

When you click "Save unified diff" in TortoiseGit, you must right-click the created `.diff` or `.patch` file and select `TortiseGit→Review/apply single patch` instead of `Apply Patch Serial...`.

Put the diff file in the root of the folder to which files you want to apply the patch to, first.

Answer (score 3):

I had a patch that looked perfectly fine, including a commit message, Author: header, etc.

I compared the output of git-format-patch, and noticed it used From: headers instead of Author: headers.

Sure enough, if you change Author: to From:, git-am applies the change cleanly.

Comment: Wow, what a gotcha! TIL. Thank you! I had a `git diff > patch` kind of a completely author-less text patch and _only_ prepending `From: me <me>` line (literally) made `git am -3` worked. Then I ran `git reset --soft HEAD~1 && git reset`, made other changes and committed the combined changes. It feels unintentional; `git am -3` should recognize `Author:` as a replacement of `From:`.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this issue. I found that I wasn't getting merge conflict with `git apply -3`, it'd just ignore those files, but the tags weren't present causing `git am -3 < example.patch` to break.

My solution to this problem was,

- use `git am -3 < example.patch`
- resolve the merge conflicts, `git mergetool`
- create a new patch with `git diff --staged > example-1.patch`
- abort and clean up the workspace, `git am --abort`, `git reset --hard HEAD`
- apply the resolved changes, `git apply example-1.patch`.
- commit the changes, `git commit`